# How to solve async setState poblem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've code below. console.log from useEffect shows current "files" value, but console.log from handleInputChange function always show previous value. I understand this is because of async setState behavour, but I don't understand how to make it work.

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import Button from '../Button/Button';
    
    function Card({ accept }) {
      let [uploadDisabled, setUploadDisabled] = useState(true);
      let [multiple, setMultiple] = useState(true);
      let [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
    
      function handleOpenClick() {
        const inputEl = document.getElementById('file');
        inputEl.click();
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(files);
      });
    
      function handleInputChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        if (!event.target.files) return;
    
        setUploadDisabled(false);
        setFiles(Array.from(event.target.files));
        console.log(files)
    
        files.forEach((file) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
    
          reader.onload = (event) => {
            const src = event.target.result;
            const alt = file.name;
          };
        });
      }
    
      return (
        <div className='card'>
          <input
            type='file'
            id='file'
            multiple={multiple}
            onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event)}
            accept={accept.join(',')}
          />
          <Button value='Open' className='btn' handleClick={handleOpenClick} />
          <Button value='Upload' className='btn primary' disabled={uploadDisabled} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Card;
```

Comment: Just use the value you _literally_ just used to set the state.

Comment: ie: `const newFiles = Array.from(event.target.files); setFiles(newfiles); console.log(newFiles); newFiles.forEach(/* etc*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (as @tkausl suggested) just use the `event.target.files` value directly instead of referencing the stale `files` value, but a "more Reacty" way to do this would be to do your `FileReader` work (and the subsequent operations) in a separate `useEffect` which runs when `files` changes:

```js
// `useEffect` in `Card` component contains code moved from `handleInputChange`
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(files)
  
  files.forEach((file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const src = event.target.result;
      const alt = file.name;
    };
  });
}, [files]);
```

Depending on what you end up doing in that `reader.onload` callback, you may want to take care to do cleanup when the `files` change (e.g. the user goes in and selects extra / different files):

```js
function addFile(file) {
  // Moved from `useEffect`
  const reader = new FileReader();

  let fileRecord = { file, reader, loaded: false };
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    const src = event.target.result;
    const alt = file.name;

    fileRecord.loaded = true;
    fileRecord.src = src;
    fileRecord.fileName = file.name;

    // whatever else
  };

  return fileRecord;
}

function removeFile(fileRecord) {
  fileRecord.reader.abort();

  if (fileRecord.loaded) {
    // cleanup
  }
}

...

  // Amended `useEffect` in `Card` component:
  useEffect(() => {
    const fileRecords = files.map(addFile);
    return () => fileRecords.map(removeFile); // cleanup
  }, [files]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you just use files from event params?

```
setFiles(Array.from(event.target.files));
```

you did it shown in the above code so you expect files to be equals to event.target.files and handle it in future with forEach

```
files.forEach((file) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = (event) => {
     const src = event.target.result;
     const alt = file.name;
   };
});
```

So you can do

```
const files = Array.from(event.target.files);

files.forEach((file) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
    
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    const src = event.target.result;
    const alt = file.name;
  };
});

setFiles(files);
```

Another point is that you need array dependency in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(files);
}, [files]);
```

Sorry for my bad english. I hope it solves.